# How to restore Line messages from Titanium Backup?

Tags: restore, titanium-backup, line

It seems that [Line](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.naver.line.android) *(a messaging app like WhatsApp)* is one that I cannot easily restore app data (messages) through Titanium Backup.

There is a [whole thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2487955), highlighting [one post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-how-to-restore-import-line-chat-history.2487955/post-47583553):

> [...]
>
> 1. Restore Line with Titanium Backup (app+data) (DON'T OPEN THE LINE APP YET!)
> 2. Log into a root shell and delete the previous settings:
>
>    ```
>    sqlite3 /data/data/jp.naver.line.android/databases/naver_line
>    delete from setting;
>    .quit
>    ```
> 3. [...]

It looks quite difficult and I am not even sure it's correct.

Can anyone confirm before I try? Also, what is a root shell? Is that some form of an app?

Comment: See [What does "to root a phone" mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236/1465) & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)

Comment: I rooted my phone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer LINE account from a phone to another without losing friends and chat history](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/121069/transfer-line-account-from-a-phone-to-another-without-loosing-friends-and-chat-h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Log into a root shell

It's a mix up of multiple things. It simply means, login into a shell and then switch to root user or alternatively, directly login as the root user. For Android, you can login from a  remote shell using *adb shell* command. It automatically logins as user 2000. Alternatively, use a terminal emulator app and it would automatically login using its own UID. In both the cases, don't bother about the term "log in".

Switch to root user using *su*.

> ```
> sqlite3 /data/data/jp.naver.line.android/databases/naver_line
> ```

[sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) is a command-line tool to interface with SQLite databases. Stock Android doesn't come with it.

That command does nothing more than attaching the database *naver_line* located under */data/data/jp.naver.line.android/databases/* to sqlite3 so that latter can do its work on it.

> ```
> delete from setting;
> ```

I don't have that app or its backup but the command indicates that there is a table named *setting* in the said database. That command would [delete all the data](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_delete_query.htm) available in that table.

> ```
> .quit
> ```

It would disconnect the database and exit from the sqlite3 tool.

---

I don't know whether those commands would achieve anything or not, so take this solution as a partial answer only.

Comment: What is CM? And stock android doesn't have command sqlite3. So how can I do it?

Comment: I don't know. You should ask the user who wrote that post. I posted this answer to translate those commands for you. :)