# LINE lite app - "All account information has been deleted as this account has been registered with the same phone number on another device"

Tags: root-access, titanium-backup, line

I can't find a way to backup my chats on LINE lite. I understand there is a way to backup and restore LINE chats on the regular LINE...LINE lite though, i am not finding ANYTHING on. The methods discussed on this site and elsewhere (such as [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139248/how-to-restore-line-messages-from-titanium-backup), [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2487955) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/121069/transfer-line-account-from-a-phone-to-another-without-loosing-friends-and-chat-h)) do not seem to be applicable with LINE lite because the file needed (Naver_line) is not present.

So what i've done is make a backup using Titanium Backup - my phone is rooted. To simulate what would happen if i later tried to restore it on another phone, i uninstalled LINE lite from my phone...clearing the cache and the data, as well as force closing the app before hitting uninstall.

I then installed it again from Google play and signed in using my email and password (same backed up  account). It then asked me to put in my number. I did that, entered the code i received through text, and logged in.

Then i went to Titanium Backup and restored only the data (3 options: App only - Data only - App+data). I go back to LINE and sure enough, my chats are all there just the way i backed them up. But seconds later, i get a pop up message saying "Sorry! All account information has been deleted as this account has been registered with the same phone number on another device" (even though its the same device - but thats not the point) and the only choice i'm given is to tap "ok".

I tap ok and i'm logged out. I have to then log in all over. When i log in, i don't see the chat. I repeat the processes with Titanium Backup, but the same thing happens. If i restore "app+data", i have to log in...and then the same thing.

Anyone has a solution for this? How can i backup and restore my chats on "LINE lite"?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Line lite app is associated with Android ID on your device.
In case you want to back up the line lite app and its data, also you will have to get the android ID from original phone.

1. Get the Android ID on ADB console with root account by typing the following command.
   In this case, the "aabbccddeeff" is the Android ID of original phone.

   ```
   # settings get secure android_id
   aabbddcceeff
   ```
2. Backup all the data of line-lite (such as with the Titanium backup app + data and `/sdcard/Android/data/com.linecorp.linelite directory`) into your PC.
3. Modify the Android ID of target phone to original one.

How to change the android ID of target phone is as follows:

1. login the shell console with root account by ADB on target phone;
2. type the following command with Android ID that you get from original phone (for example aabbccddeeff);

   ```
   # settings put secure android_id aabbccddeeff
   ```
3. reboot the target phone;
4. move all of the backed up data from your PC to the target phone ;
5. on the target phone, restore the line-line app + data by using Titanium backup app and `/sdcard/Android/data/com.linecorp.linelite directory`;
6. launch the Line Lite app on your target phone.

Now, you will see the chat history with line lite app on your target phone.

I think the  points are:

1. same Android ID is required both original phone and target phone
2. App+Data of line lite app by Titanium backup
3. `/sdcard/Android/data/com.linecorp.linelite` directory

I hope you will succeed in the backup and restore the all data (including chat history) of line lite.