# LINE Messenger backup/restore under microG?

Tags: line, micro-g

**NOTE**: I see the following similar discussion here:
[How to restore Line messages from Titanium Backup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139248/how-to-restore-line-messages-from-titanium-backup)
Although that discussion offers a suggestion that might partially apply to what I want to ask here, it does not confirm the validity of that suggestion. Therefore, it does not actually answer my following question:

I'm thinking of switching to `microG`, but a stumbling block is `LINE Messenger`. I know that it can run under `microG`, but I also know that it can't normally back up and restore `LINE Messenger` chat history without access to `Google Drive`.

I have an idea of how I might be able to bypass this restriction, but I'm wondering if it actually would be feasible. Here's my idea ...

(1) Under my current non-`microG` Android OS, take a backup of `/data/data/jp.naver.line.android`

(2) Install `microG`, and then install `LINE Messenger`.

(3) Restore the previously backed up `jp.naver.line.android` to `/data/data` under the `microG` OS.

(4) Take periodic backups of `/data/data/jp.naver.line.android` as I use `LINE` under `microG`.

(5) If i ever want to restore my `LINE` history under `microG`, repeat step 3 with the latest `jp.naver.line.android` backup.

A variation might be to only back up and restore one or more appropriate `sqlite` databases that are resident within `/data/data/jp.naver.line.android`, instead of that entire directory tree.

I'm willing to experiment with this approach, but before I do, I'm wondering whether anyone has tried anything like this with `LINE Messenger` under `microG`.

Thank you in advance for any thoughts and suggestions.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to @Andrew-T for the pointer to the other discussion that I missed, which indeed confirms that backup and restore for the database under `/data/data/jp.naver.line.android` can actually be done.

I'm just wondering if anyone has actually gotten something like this to work specifically under `microG`. I'd like to switch to `microG`, but it would give me more confidence to take that step if anyone has already been able to do this in order to get full `LINE` functionality under that OS, including backup and restore.

**FURTHER UPDATE**: That other discussion is more than 7 years old, and sadly, it turns out that the information is outdated. The `/data/data/jp.naver.line.android/databases` directory that is referred to in that article doesn't contain the database that is mentioned. Furthermore, I checked each and every other database in that directory, and none of them contain any chat history.

I also checked all of the other files and directories under `/data/data/jp.naver.line.android`, and none of them contain any chat history, either.

This is consistent with `LINE`'s decision a while ago to stop allowing local-storage backup and to make Google Drive the only location to where chat history can be backed up and restored from. In conjunction with that decision, `LINE` seems to have gotten rid of all local chat history data from its device-resident databases.

So, it looks like I'm out of luck regarding non-Google-based backup and restore for `LINE`.

However, I'll keep this question open for a while longer, in case it turns out that someone knows of another way I can manage Android-based `LINE` backups and restores without Google being in the picture.

**PS**: Hmm ... I wonder if it would be possible to create a fake "Google Drive" service which looks just like Google Drive to `LINE`, but which actually just manages a data store of my own.

I'm going to look into this and report back if I have any luck with this idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Transfer LINE account from a phone to another without losing friends and chat history](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/121070/44325). Note that without root, `/data/data/jp.naver.line.android` cannot be accessed.

Comment: I missed that one discussion, thank you! But I can't find anything which says whether or not this would work with `microG`. It seems like it should work, but it would give me more confidence about switching to `microG` if anyone has actually been successful with this procedure under `microG`.

Comment: It turns out that the information in that other thread seems to be outdated. It's more than 7 years old. None of the data stored under `/data/data/jp.naver.line.android/data bases` contains any chat history.  See the "Further Update" section of my question for more details.

Comment: I figured out how to do it! See my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround!!

I have an old Mac laptop. There is a Mac desktop version of `LINE Messenger`, and that version does allow chat history backups and restores.

So, I can run `LINE` under `microG` and just do the chat backups and restores on the Mac.

Also, I can run an `Automator` script on the Mac periodically when it's idle in order to start `LINE`, and then to issue the appropriate mouse clicks to go to the Settings and initiate the chat backup. This will allow me to keep the `LINE` chats backed up on a regular basis.

Also, I'm guessing that chat backups and restores will probably also be available on the `Windows` desktop version of `LINE`, in case anyone has a `Windows` box and wants to try the same thing.

This is probably the closest I can come to what I was originally asking for here, and it's an acceptable Answer to my question.

Now, I no longer have any obstacles to starting my official move to `microG`.

**PS**: If I want to get fancy, I could write a script on the Mac to initiate the `Automater` script that I described above, and I then could create a `Tasker` shortcut on my `microG` device to `ssh` to the Mac and invoke that script. This way, I could actually initiate the `LINE` chat history backup from my `microG` device.

And I could handle `LINE` chat history restores in these same ways.

**PPS**: And it turns out that the Mac `LINE` implementation optionally allows a proxy to be used between `LINE` and the backup/restore host.  If I want to get ***really***, ***really*** fancy some day, I might be able to write my own custom proxy server which emulates a connection to `Google Drive`, but which actually just saves the chat history in my own, personal data store.

That is a longer term project for some possibly never-arriving time in my future when I actually might find myself with a lot of spare time.