# Recover old Naver Line messages from Titanium Backup

Tags: line

Ok, I recently flashed my Samsung S7 with the latest stock firmware and rooted it so all my files got deleted. I did a backup on Titanium but my mistake was that after rooting, I logged on my Line (without restoring the Line backup first) and clicked yes to deleting the messages in "the other device". Stupid, I know.

I know Line recognizes devices based on Android ID. So the new Android ID on my latest firmware is now the default account and I got logged out on my "old device" with my previous Android ID.

I tried restoring Line on Titanium without restoring my previous Android ID (since my new Android ID is now the default) but it doesn't work, Line simply crashes and would not launch.

Now I am fine if there is really no way to use my old chat history on my new firmware. What I just want is at least be able to recover my Line messages from the Titanium Backup file. It's got all my messages from years back, so many important and sentimental stuff in there, including money I paid to my landlord lol.

Any ideas? Thanks!

PS
I really wish Line would stop this security feature of using only one device for one account. Heck I wish they just follow Facebook messenger and upload all data to the cloud so that it won't be a huge headache when people migrate to new devices.

Comment: TiBu has the feature of restoring or changing Android ID,, IIRC. Maybe you can flash ROM again , restore to earlier ID and restore line - you would of course lose  current messages

Comment: See this for restoring ID https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ms-android-motorola&q=titanium+backup+restore+Android+ID&oq=titanium+backup+restore+Android+ID&aqs=mobile-gws-lite..

Comment: that's not what I meant. restoring my old Android ID will not work because it's not the default ID anymore attached to my account. But anyway, I still did it and Line simply crashed

Comment: I believe the solution to this question is the answer at https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/121069/transfer-line-account-from-a-phone-to-another-without-loosing-friends-and-chat-h I let you decide whether the question is a duplicate or not, cheers!