# LINE Letter Sealing - Unable to display message as it couldn't be decrypted

Tags: encryption, line

[LINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(software)) is a chat application.

I recently reinstalled my OS, and restored my LINE chat history using [this procedure](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/121069).

Problem: Some of my chats appear like this:

[image]

It says:

> Letter Sealing
>   Unable to display message as it couldn't be decrypted. Please ask your friend to resend the message.

As you can see, my friend re-sending me the message does not solve the problem.

On the messages from July 6 to the day I reinstalled have this problem.

So I disabled Letter Sealing, and now I can read new messages sent to me (but I can still not read the existing problematic messages).

Questions:

- How to make the problematic messages readable again? I still have the Titanium Backup from the former OS, if necessary.
- Is there a way to re-enable Letter Sealing while making sure that encrypted messages will stay readable even after reinstalling my OS in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. The second method on [this page](http://messingwithtech.blogspot.com/2013/11/restoring-chat-messages-in-line.html) worked for me.

### Steps:

1. Do a previous backup
2. copy `/data/data/jp.naver.line.android/databases/naver_line` to your PC and rename it to `naver_line_old`
3. Reinstall and do a fresh setup of LINE
4. copy the new `naver_line` to your PC and rename it to `naver_line_new`
5. In your PC, open and copy the `chat_history` table from `naver_line_old`(I used [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt)) and paste it on `naver_line_new`, having previously deleted `chat_history` from it
6. copy `naver_line_new` to `/data/data/jp.naver.line.android/databases/naver_line`(rename it as `naver_line`)
7. Restart your phone

Letter sealing should work OK now; unfortunately, I don't know how to make the problematic messages readable again.

I hope to have solved your problem.